# sql with subquery issue

Tags: sql

I have the following query:

```
    SELECT  PROGID1 = P.Prog, ENTERDATE1 = MAX(ENTERDATE), 
    BANKID = (select B.BANKID from BANK B
              WHERE B.ID = PROGID1 and B.ENTERDATE = ENTERDATE1 
             )  
   FROM PROTOCOL P JOIN BANK B ON P.ID = B.ID 
   group by P.ID
```

What I need to do is to get the BANKID for a given MAX(ENTERDATE) but as BANKID has duplicate records, I need to find it based on what the MAX ENTERDATE
was. I tried to do the following but I get a message saying invalid column name PROGID1 and ENTERDATE1  inside of:

```
    (select B.BANKID from BANK B
     WHERE B.ID = PROGID1 and B.ENTERDATE = ENTERDATE1 
              )
```

Comment: Can you post the actual error message?

Comment: **What** database system, and which version?? **SQL** is just the Structured Query Language - a language used by many database systems - SQL is **NOT** a database product... stuff like this is very often vendor-specific - so we really need to know what database system you're using....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this? I.e., use the "protocol" query as a table.

```
SELECT b.bank_id
  FROM bank b
     , ( SELECT id AS progid1, MAX(enterdate) AS enterdate1
           FROM protocol
          GROUP BY prog
       ) p
 WHERE b.id = p.progid1
   AND b.enterdate = p.enterdate1
```

P.S. I think you used "p.prog" where you meant p.id.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that `EnterDate` is a column in the `Bank` table, since this is the one that you indicated had multiple records...

```
SELECT
    p.Prog,
    b.EnterDate
    b.BankID
FROM
    Protocol p JOIN 
    Bank b ON b.ID = p.ID AND b.EnterDate = (
        SELECT MAX(b2.EnterDate) AS MaxEnterDate
        FROM Bank b2
        WHERE b2.ID = p.ID
    )
```